# How to get the CURRENT filter string of a (sub-) form, filtered manually at runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to update only the rows of a table filtered in a form by the user.
It seems clever to use directly the filter currently applied to the form (me.filter). Unfortunately it is not updated right away. I need to switch the form to edit and back to form view in order to get the real value of me.filter.

Details: using Access 2013, the form is a sub-form

How can I update the value of me.Filter according to the currently and manually set criteria?

Or to reformulate the question: **How can I get the CURRENT filter string of a (sub-) form?**

```
Public Sub SetSelect()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim temp As Variant

    'unsuccessful tries to update me.filter
    temp = Me.FilterOn
    Me.FilterOn = False
    Me.FilterOn = temp
    Me.Parent.Requery
    Debug.Print Me.Filter
    '--- actual code

    If Me.FilterOn Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE Bauteile SET Auswahl = true WHERE " & Me.Filter & ";"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        strSQL = "UPDATE Bauteile SET Auswahl = false WHERE not(" & Me.Filter & ");"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    Else
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Bauteile set Auswahl= true"
    End If

End Sub
```

Update:
I found the code snippet above in the net. http://www.supportnet.de/t/2219076
Obviously it worked in 2009. Would it be an Access 2013 issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "update" a filter, you set it. So it is not quite clear what you are trying to do.

Perhaps it is rather something like:

```
Public Sub SetSelect()

    Dim strSQL As String

    If Me.FilterOn Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE Bauteile SET Auswahl = (" & Me.Filter & ");"
    Else
        strSQL = "UPDATE Bauteile SET Auswahl = True;"
    End If
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    Me.Parent.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Me.filter is unknown, the user filters the form by arbitrary criteria. I want to get the filter string of this manual operation. This is meant to get a subset of the whole table, then apply an update query to the subset. The value of this string is stored in me.filter once you leave the "form view".

Comment: The code should work similar to this, though I don't know what you mean by "leaving form view".

Comment: by "leaving form view", I mean either closing the form, or setting it in "design mode". Only when I do so, does the filter property of the form update. I also would think that the code should work, alas...

Comment: I was so free as to change the title of the question.